# Sum of indexed numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have an array of indices:

```
I=[0 1 2 3 0 3]
```

And array of values:

```
W=[w0, w1, w2, w3]
```

How can I create an array `X` using vectorized numpy expressions produced as follows:

```
X = np.zeros(I.max() + 1)
for i in range(len(I)):
   X[I[i]] += W[I[i]]
```

In the above example `X=[w0+w0, w1, w2, w3+w3]`

Comment: Is `I` sorted ?

Comment: @Psidom It's not, but it's not too difficult to sort it, result won't change; do you know solution with sorted `I`?

Comment: Can you update your result with updated `I`? I am not sure what you are trying to do now.

Comment: Are you sure your loop is right? It looks to me like you're walking off the end of `X`. You seem to have the indices for `X` and `W` switched.

Comment: Your code, as-written, will not work.  `I.max()` is `3`, which sets the length of `X` to 3, but you are iterating `i` with values up to `4`.  When `i == 4`, you will get an indexing error for `X[i]`

Comment: you mean `X = np.zeros(I.max()+1)`

Comment: Fixed loop and example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with reproducible objects

```
>>> I = np.r_[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3]
>>> W = np.r_[60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
>>> M = W[I]
```

Then note that one has

```
>>> W[I]
array([60, 50, 40, 30, 60, 30])
>>> W[W[I]==W]
array([60, 50, 40, 30])
>>> np.unique(W[I], return_counts=True)[1]
array([2, 1, 1, 2])
```

Finally, what about doing

```
>>> W[M==W]*np.unique(M, return_counts=True)[1] #  X
array([120, 50, 40, 60])
```

---

Let's (almost) do that with strings

```
>>> W = np.array(['w0', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5'])
>>> M = W[I]
>>> M
array(['w0', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w0', 'w3'], dtype='|S2')
>>> W[M==W]
array(['w0', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3'], dtype='|S2')
>>> np.unique(W[I], return_counts=True)[1]
array([2, 1, 1, 2])
```

Which leads to mentally consider

```
>>> [2*'w0', 'w1', 'w2', 2*'w3']
```

Comment: but you've given answer to the latest questions, seems work, just trying to check it

Comment: your answer matches the latest question, not the original one, since [120, 50, 40, 60] == [w0+w0, w1, w2, w3+w5], not the [w0+w4, w1, w2, w3+w5], so probably makes sense to remove your comment in the beginning

Comment: @DikobrAz. Yes you are rigth. 3AM here.

Comment: well, I've confused myself three times when asking this question, so I'm not the one to blame you @Kanak :)